# Remove certain option having an index in ddslick

Tags: javascript, jquery, json

I need to remove an option of ddslick on button click

```
        $('#ddslick_id').ddslick('remove', {index: 0});
```

This is the link for the code https://jsfiddle.net/5tpy4ofb/17/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have checked the code for this `ddslick` plugin at the GitHub page and there is no such method called "remove" which you are trying in your fiddle;

However you can get this sorted out if you go the jQuery way like,

`$('#VehicleType').find('.dd-option-selected').remove();`

Just in case if you don't to use the selected item and want to delete any one of the item, They have provided a `<input type='hidden'...>` with a value for every option of the select box, perhaps you can use that as an index, I tried retrieving the value as,

`$('#VehicleType .dd-option-selected').find(':input').val();`

Hope this helps!

Comment: I don't have to delete the selected option, I need to delete a particular option, say the 3rd and 4th options on button click

Comment: In that case, how will you pass the `index` value for selection?,

Comment: I couldn't get the `index` value or the `id` of the `dd-select-option` ... That is what I've been trying to do. If I can get any of those values, I would use `remove` or `detach` to delete them from the select list

Comment: Yup, true, I have checked the documentation too, there is no way to get the selected index of `ddslick` component as it is not a real select control and it is basically a div based one.

Comment: How can I delete specific options in this `ddslick` then?

Comment: They have provided a `<input type='hidden'...>` with a value for every option of the select box, perhaps you can use that as an index, I tried retrieving the value as, `$('#VehicleType .dd-option-selected').find(':input').val();`

Comment: Yeah... I've used the same technique and the problem has been solved. :) Thank you! for helping